# Search text file and save to specific variables

Tags: python

I have looked at the previous questions and answers to my question but can't seem to get this to work. I am very new to python so I apologize in advance for this basic question.

I am running a Monte Carlo simulation in a separate piece of software. It creates a text file output that is quite lengthy. I want to retrieve 3 values that are under one heading. I have created the following code that isolates the part of the text file I want.

```
f = open("/Users/scott/Desktop/test/difinp0.txt","rt")
difout = f.readlines()
f.close()

d = range(1,5)

for i, line in enumerate(difout):
    if "Chi-Square Test for Difference Testing" in line:
        for l in difout[i:i+5]: print(l)
```

This produces the following:

Chi-Square Test for Difference Testing

```
      Value                             12.958
      Degrees of Freedom                    10
      P-Value                           0.2261
```

Note: there is a blank line between the heading and the next line titled "Value."

There are a different statistics with the same labels in the output but I need the ones here that are under the heading "Chi-square Test for Difference Testing.

What I am looking for is to save the values into 3 variables for use later.

chivalue (which in this case would be 12.958

chidf (which in this case would be 10)

chip (which in this case would be 0.2261

I've tried to enumerate "l" and retrieve from there but I can't seem to get it to work.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Again, apologies for such a basic question.

Comment: can you split() your line using a delimiter of some sort? also can you include sample file input?

Comment: Would you be opposed to using a dictionary instead of variables? It is difficult to declare multiple variables in a loop. EDIT: never mind, I think I misunderstood what you're looking to do

Comment: Could you be specific about how would your text file look like and how you want your output to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to build a function that parses the input lines and returns the variables you want

```
def parser(text_lines):
    v, d, p = [None]*3
    for line in text_lines:
        if line.strip().startswith('Value'):
            v = float(line.strip().split(' ')[-1])
        if line.strip().startswith('Degrees'):
            d = float(line.strip().split(' ')[-1])
        if line.strip().startswith('P-Value'):
            p = float(line.strip().split(' ')[-1])
    return v,d,p

for i, line in enumerate(difout):
    if "Chi-Square Test for Difference Testing" in line:
        for l in difout[i:i+5]: 
            print(l)
        value, degree, p_val = parser(difout[i:i+5])
```